# Is it possible to use build.gradle in conjunction with BuildConfig.groovy?

Tags: grails, gradle

I'm currently using Grails 2.5.4, and so we're still running depending on `BuildConfig.groovy`.

The reason I want to use `build.gradle` is because of the following plugin:

https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin

However, obviously, since we're still going through `BuildConfig.groovy`, my `build.gradle` file does not get executed.

I know we have the following grails-gradle plugin:

> https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin

However, it looks like this will completely replace `grails.project.dependency.resolution` in `BuildConfig.groovy`. Additionally, this will require the other team members to use `gradle grails-run-app` instead of `grails run-app`. I do not want to introduce this big of a change.

So basically, is there a way just do a simple `grails run-app`, have the dependencies resolved through `BuildConfig.groovy` as well as `build.gradle`?

Perhaps this is impossible, but I just wanted to see if anyone has done this before.